# How to resolve the issue as when ever i opened my laptop it shows your battery critically Low?

Tags: battery, battery-life, dell-vostro

I have the Dell Vostro 3546 model, it  can be used from 2 years nearly but from last one week onwords i faced the major problem as when i charged my battery full and then shutdown my laptop, after one day i open my Laptop then press powerbutton to turn on my laptop it displays the Your Battery critically low. Please press F1 key to contiune. but before shutdown i filled my laptop battery with full charge.

Please tell me what is the Problem and how can i resolve it.

Pradeep

Comment: your battery isn't draining, rather it's giving no backup...you probably need to change the battery.

Comment: An easy check for whether the problem is a dying battery vs. not actually powering off or being woken:  Charge the battery overnight & verify that it reads fully charged.  Then disconnect the charger and run it for normal use on just the battery.  If you get anything close to normal run time, the issue isn't the battery.  If you get just a short run time, plug the charger back in and use it for hours.  If you have no strange power problems, the charger is OK.  It's theoretically possible that the problem is with the internal charging circuit, but the most likely culprit would be the battery.

Comment: I was already tried the above scenario like I charged the battery full and disconnect then I am running my laptop with battery usage its working properly upto 4 hours.
but when I was charged my battery full and then shutdown my laptop, after one day I reopened my laptop the complete battery drains because its always shows your battery critically low.

Answer (score 1):

While I have seen very rare cases caused by a bad charger, this is almost always caused by a dying battery.

To be 100% sure, you'd need to try replacing one or the other, but if you need to buy a replacement, your odds are 100:1 that the battery should be replaced.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the battery is charging pretty normally and drains somewhat quicker than normal, thus the battery is not completely bad.

What can however be a problem, is microsofts default crappy powersave settings, that priorities a stupid "power save" mode in front of turning off the laptop completely.

Its because your laptop enters powersaving mode instead of turning off.
This can also happen if you close the lid while shutting down. The laptop then enters powersave mode, and is on (which is signifyed by a flashing power button or power led) instead of shutting off completely.

This literally DRAINS the battery.

Suggestion: Change your energy saver settings to only turn off the screen when lid is shut.
And change energy saver settings to TURN OFF the laptop completely when you push the power button or turn off from the start menu.

If you want to save battery when you close the lid, you can also tell the computer to turn off completely when lid is closed.

To access powersave settings, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and a box will appear.
In this box, write `control powercfg.cpl` and press enter.